# ¿Cómo probar un método de una clase llamado por un eventListener?

Tags: javascript, mocha, web-components

Estoy desarrollando un web omponent usando [LitElement](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/) y a la hora de ejecutar pruebas unitarias me estoy encontrando con que cuando compruebo si un método se ha llamado al añadir un eventListener y éste dice no haber sido llamado.

Este es un ejemplo de lo que estoy intentando hacer.

### Mi Componente

```js
import { LitElement, html, css } from 'lit-element';

export default class MyComponent extends LitElement {

    myAction() {
        console.log('hola');
    }

    render() {
        return html`
            <button @click="${this.myAction}">Click Me</button>
        `;
    }

}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

### Mi Test

```js
import {
  html,
  fixture,
  expect,
} from '@open-wc/testing';

import './miComponente.js';

describe('test', () => {
  let element;
  let sandbox;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    element = await(fixture(html`<my-element></my-element>`));
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  })

  afterEach(() => { sandbox.restore(); })

  it('should call myAction method when button is clicked', () => {
    const button = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('button');
    sandbox.spy(element, 'myAction');
    button.click();
    expect(element.myAction.calledOnce).to.be.true;
  })
});
```

Tambien he probado a poner el espía en `sandbox.spy(element.myAction, 'bind')` por si fuera que lit-html aplica un bind, pero tampoco es eso.

¿Alguna idea de por qué puede ser y cómo proceder?

Como Test Runner estoy usando Karma y uso Sinon, Chai y las herramientas que ofrece @open-wc.

Tengo constancia de que el método se está llamando, como se puede ver en el siguiente ejemplo.

```html
<script type="module">

// Lo embebo en el HTML porque el editor de SO me está dando error

import {LitElement, html} from 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/lit-element@latest/lit-element.js?module';

export default class MyComponent extends LitElement {

    myAction() {
        console.log('hola');
    }

    render() {
        return html`
            <button @click="${this.myAction}">Click Me</button>
        `;
    }

}

customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent);

</script>

<my-component></my-component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras estar investigando y trabajando sobre este problema he descubierto que lo que hace LitElement y lit-html con este `@click` es añadir el contexto al método mediante un `.call()`. He modificado el test a

```js
it('should call myAction method when button is clicked', () => {
    const button = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('button');
    sandbox.spy(element.myAction, 'call');
    button.click();
    expect(element.myAction.call.calledOnce).to.be.true;
  })
```

y para este caso el test pasa correctamente.

No tengo muy claro por qué sinon no es capaz de detectar que el método se ha llamado cuando se le aplica `.call()` pero así es como he solucionado el problema.